# Simplify $x/(x-2)+(x-1)/(x+1)=-1$ step by step

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $$x/(x-2)+(x-1)/(x+1)=-1$$ step by step.

So I clear the fractions by multiplying by the common denominator of $(x-2)(x+1)$ and you have
$$x(x+1) + (x-1)(x-2) = -(x-2)(x+1)$$
$$x^2 + x + x^2 - 3x + 2 = -x^2 + x + 2$$
$$3x^2 - 3x = 0$$
$$x(x-1) = 0$$
$$x = 0,1$$

I feel this is wrong. It there a simpler way to solve this equation?

Comment: Well, $x=0$ and $1$ are indeed solutions of the original equation. Why do you feel it is wrong?

Comment: I think you right maybe I am over thinking this.

Comment: You just have to substitute either $0$ or $1$ to the left-hand side of the original equation and check that it simplifies to $-1$.

Comment: @CodeVista Welcome to Math SE. Note each of your steps is reversible, i.e., you could start at the bottom and work your way to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach.

You just have to bear in mind the proposed transformations are not equivalent.

Having said that, you can keep your solution and check the results to know if they satisfy the original equation as suggested by @Gary.

Alternatively, you could consider to proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{x - 2} + \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} = -1 & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x(x + 1) + (x - 1)(x - 2) = -(x - 2)(x + 1)\\\\
(x - 2)(x + 1) \neq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

which leads to the obtained solutions.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score -1):

> Comment by Gary

> You just have to substitute either 0 or 1 to the left-hand side of the original equation and check that it simplifies to −1.

It is important to understand the consequences of the OP's (i.e. original poster's) analysis.

You started with a specific constraint, C-1.

Then in effect, you deduced that any value for $x$ that satisfies C-1, must also satisfy equation E-1, which was the first equation that you originated.

Then, your analysis deduced that if equation E-1 is satisfied, then equation E-2 must also be satisfied.

....

This process was continued until you reached the point of saying

If equation E-n is satisfied, then $x$ must be an element in the set $S$ of $\{candidate-value-1, candidate-value-2, ...\}$.

In this particular problem, $S$ had two candidate values.

---

So, what has been accomplished (so far) is that if $x$ satisfies C-1 then $x$ is an element in the set $S$.

This does not imply that every element in the set $S$ will satisfy C-1.  However, it does imply that no other value for $x$ can satisfy C-1, besides the elements in the set $S$.

This explains the comment of Gary, that I excerpted at the start of my answer.

---

This is where the dissection of the situation gets interesting.  The question is being begged: under what circumstances will every value in the generated set $S$ automatically satisfy C-1?  Alternatively, under what circumstances will the set $S$ contain *extraneous* candidate values that do not satisfy C-1?

To answer this question, you have to dissect the each step of the analytical process.  When, for example, it was reasoned that

*C-1 implies E-1*

was this analysis a one-way implication or a two-way implication

(i.e. *C-1 if and only if E-1*).

In the present problem, as it turns out, each step was an if and only if step.  This explains why the set $S$ contained no extraneous values.

You get a feel for when you are generating a one-way implication, rather than two-way (if and only if) implication.

The typical example is $x = 3 \implies x^2 = 9.$

---

However, this type of dissection is actually unnecessary.  If you **always** regard the set $S$ as a set of candidate values, each of which must be manually verified, then you never have to worry about whether the set $S$ has extraneous values.

This means that this approach relieves you of ever having to worry that one of your implications was **not** a two-way implication.